# generalizing scalar inputs to array inputs for user-defined fucntions

Tags: arrays, matlab

The `round` function can take a scalar and operate on it. However it can also take an array and operate on it in expected manner.

```
>> round(2.3)

ans =

     2

>> round([2.3,3.4])

ans =

     2     3
```

I similarly have a function and want it to work in the ""expected"" manner for array inputs. It works well for scalar inputs. I could run a `for` loop and evaluate my function on each element of the array but what other smarter ways do i have available?

**For further concreteness**, i have:

```
function [a,b]=func(c,d,e,f)
```

And i have `d,e,f` but i want to evaluate the function to several values of `c`:-

```
g=[];
for i=1:10
    [a,b]=func(c(i),d,e,f);
    g=[g;[a,b]];
end
```

I am not fully sure how to apply `arrayfun` though i believe it is what i should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the *arrayfun* function.
Here is the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html

Say, I have this function:

```
function res = myTest(a,b)
size(a) % for checking that we work on each element
res = a+1;
res = res +b;
```

I have a matrix *A*

```
A = magic(3);
```

I want to apply *myTest* with *a* equal to each element in *A*

```
A1 = arrayfun(@(x) myTest(x,2),A)
```

(*x* is replaced by the elements of the array declared after the comma)

Comment: i see, i have added some queries based on your suggestion in my question. Can you help?